# Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/guardian/android/androidx/compose/compose-compiler/1.0.0/compose-compiler-1.0.0.pom'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to setup jetpack compose for an existing project but i'm having the above error when i trying to run the app after synchronized the gradle files.

This is how my **build.gradle (project)** looks like:

```
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'
        ext.compose_version = '1.0.0'
    
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
            classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
            classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.0'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
            classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
        }
    }
    
    plugins {
        id "com.github.hierynomus.license" version "0.14.0"
    }

....
```

and this is how my **build.gradle(Module)** looks like:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 30
        buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.app.schedulicity"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 30
            versionCode 82
            versionName "10.0.9"
            renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
            multiDexEnabled true
            testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    
            // Room migration helper: expose the schema
            kapt {
                arguments {
                    arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas".toString())
                }
            }
    
            // Room migration testing: adding the schema location as an asset folder
            sourceSets {
                androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
    
                String sharedTestDir = 'src/sharedTest/java'
    
                debugTesting {
                    java.srcDir sharedTestDir
                    resources.srcDirs += ['src/test/resources']
                }
            }
    
            javaCompileOptions {
                annotationProcessorOptions {
                    arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
                }
            }
    
            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            }
        }
    
        buildFeatures {
            compose = true
            viewBinding true
        }
    
        composeOptions {
            kotlinCompilerVersion = "1.5.10"
            kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }

....
```

If i synch the project all looks good but when i try to compile then the error happens. As you can see i haven't include any dependency to the project yet.

Maybe some of you have faced with this problem before and have a solution :)

Comment: did you add google repository to your module build.gradle files?

Answer (score 0):

Of course the error will occur. The error does not occur in sync since there is nothing wrong with the added dependencies. Everything is downloaded and works fine. When you try to compile, it doesn't because you have not added the compose compiler dependency. How would it compile when the compiler itself is missing?

Create a dummy project using the studio templates and copy the dependencies from there.

Or visit here

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/adding